# How to create a dynamic relation on the basis of column value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple case but can't get my head around how to implement it using `ActiveRecord`. So I have class user which can have one `profile` and also has a column `role` which is an enum. Looks something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum role: { manager: 1, writer: 2 }

    has_one :profile
end
```

Similarly I have `Writer` and `Manager` which `belongs_to` user

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class Writer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I am struggling to point `profile` attribute of user to correct profile either writer or manager based on role enum. I cannot use polymorphic relations since user is the parent and profile tables (writer and manager) depend on it.

Any help will be apperciated

Comment: Why don't you use `profile` as polymorphic associated with `manager` `writer` and `common user` , i think this would be simple.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

I don't think you could define a `has_many` with a dynamic "table name" (a.k.a. dynamic model), mainly because there is no dynamic equivalent SQL string to represent say something like below:

```
# Let's pretend that you have a `Post` model `belongs_to :user` and has an attribute `is_enabled:boolean`
# and that `User` `has_one :post`...

User.joins(:post).where(posts: { is_enabled: true })
# would generate an SQL
# User Load (0.6ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "posts"."is_enabled" = true LIMIT 1

# ^ This works fine because `has_one :posts` always is mapped to the `posts` table
# but since you are asking for a dynamic one, then see an equivalent below

User.joins(:profile).where(":managers or :writers": { is_enabled: true })
# User Load (0.6ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "what_table" on "what_table"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "what_table"."is_enabled" = true LIMIT 1
# ^ which as you could see does not have an exact SQL equivalent because it is
# "trying to" INNER JOIN on a "dynamic" table. You can do this per `User` record,
# because you know what to INNER JOIN with, but for a collection of `User` records,
# there is no such SQL "dynamic-table-name-matching" equivalent.
```

### Alternative Solution:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: { manager: 1, writer: 2 }

  has_one :manager
  has_one :writer

  def profile
    case role
    when 'manager' then manager
    when 'writer' then writer
    else raise NotImplementedError
    end
  end

  # or if you prefer a dynamic-matching one:
  # def profile
  #   send(role.to_sym)
  # end
end
```

#### Usage Example

```
# rails console
user = User.first
puts user.profile
# => returns either <Manager...>, <Writer...>, or nil
```

*Caveat though is Alternative Solution above defines `profile` as a **method** and not an **association**, therefore you'll lose the ability to do a `INNER JOIN`s (which you wouldn't probably be able to do anyway; see my TL;DR above as to why)*